# creating a document database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I camse across an old post which had the pefect solution for my requirement - 'Creating a Document Database Using Microsoft Access' with the answer provided by Renaud BomPuis in the form of a sample database (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52900980/StackOverflow/SO25044339.accdb).

I have been able to manipulate the source code for this to suit my needs and successfully insert it into my main database.  The only problem I have is that it creates a new record at the wrong point for me.  When the user clicks 'Upload File' a new record is created and a form opens to be able to select the file using file dialog.  But if the user changes their mind and clicks cancel, the record is already created but empty of a file path.

I would like to be able to only create a new record if the user confirms it but I cannot seem to manipulate the code into the correct order for it to work.

Can anybody help please?  Many thanks.

EDIT: Code from comment

```vb
Private Sub btnUploadDoc_Click() ' Create a new record in the Documents table for the selected Works No 
Dim DocID As Variant 
Dim db As dao.Database 
Dim rs As dao.Recordset 

Set db = CurrentDb() 
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblDocuments", dbOpenDynaset, dbFailOnError) 
With rs 
    .AddNew !WorksNo = cboWorksNo 
    .Update 
    .Move 0, .LastModified 
    DocID = !DocID 
    .Close 
End With 
Set rs = Nothing 
Set db = Nothing 
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDocSelect", WhereCondition:="DocID=" & DocID 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code on button click  Upload file please? In our corporate network I cannot download the db

Comment: Private Sub btnUploadDoc_Click()
    ' Create a new record in the Documents table for the selected Works No
    Dim DocID As Variant
    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblDocuments", dbOpenDynaset, dbFailOnError)
    With rs
        .AddNew
            !WorksNo = cboWorksNo
        .Update
        .Move 0, .LastModified
        DocID = !DocID
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDocSelect", WhereCondition:="DocID=" & DocID
End Sub

Comment: I assume your doc select code is in the frmDocSelect form. You should post that too (but edit your original post and wrap the code in code tags - like @Andre did for you the last time). I think it's probably simpler if you have check the upload file before you create a new record - and just do that on your current form - before you open the new record

Answer (score 0):

This will not be a trivial change, since (I assume) `frmDocSelect` depends on an existing record in `tblDocuments`.

The best way to proceed is probably to simply delete the new record if the user clicks Cancel.

Something like

```vb
Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Dim DocID As Long
    DocID = Me.DocID
    ' Close form before deleting, to avoid a flicker of "#Deleted"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblDocuments WHERE DocID=" & DocID
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the replies.  I'm going to try Andre's delete solution and Ill let you know how I get on.